# How to use custom traefik.toml file?

Tags: traefik

I use this file:

```
version: '2'

services:
  proxy:
    image: traefik
    command: --web --configFile=/traefik.toml --docker --docker.domain=docker.localhost --logLevel=DEBUG
    networks:
      - webgateway
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /dev/null:/traefik.toml

networks:
  webgateway:
    driver: bridge
```

And I'm trying to use my custom config: traefik.toml in my traefik folder but it's not working.

This is my folder structure:

```
traefik:
    docker-compose.yml
    traefik.toml
```

Thanks,
Noam

Answer (score 1):

You are mapping `/dev/null` on the host to the Traefik configuration file inside the container. Instead, try to bind-mount the actual configuration file into the container, i.e.:

./traefik.toml:/traefik.toml

Comment: Sorry I'm really new with it. So it will need to looks like that:     volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - traefik.toml:/traefik.toml

Comment: @Noamway basically yes, though you'll need to add a leading dot and slash if your Traefik configuration file sits local to your docker-compose specification. I updated my answer accordingly.